# Jquery plugin DataTables individual column filtering on top?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I use this api with DataTables : http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/dataTables/example_multi_filter.html

But How I can put seach inputs above the table, next to "Search all columns"??

Answer (score 20):

You could try with CSS:

```
tfoot {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use column filter add-on for DataTables. It can be configured to place filters below and above the heading row. See http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dateRange.html, http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/numberRange.html and other examples on the site.

Quick update: The two URLs above are invalid now.  Here's a working one: https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/

Answer (score 1):

**Put column filtering on top (OR After Head) in Jquery Datatable:**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
```

TABLE

```
<table class="display table table-hover table-bordered" id="usersShops"  width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Shop Name</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Visit Date</th>
            <th>IsVisited</th>
            <th>IsAppdownloaded</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ShopName</th>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>VisitDate</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>        
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Modified Code Of Column filter :

```
oTable.columnFilter({
                sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
                aoColumns: [{ type: "text" },
                            { type: "text" },
                            { type: "date-range" }
                ]
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very old post. But we can achive this by doing below changes to your jquery code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mytable thead td').each( function () {
        var title = $('#mytable thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
});
$("#mytable thead input").on( 'keyup change', function () {
        table
            .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
});
});
```